# Problem deploying shiny app using github package

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy a shiny app to the shinyapps.io server. The app creates a map of Denmark for two different indicators in two different years 2004 and 2005. To create the map I use the package called mapDK, which is from GitHub:

```
devtools::install_github("sebastianbarfort/mapDK")
```

The app seems to run fine locally, however when I try to deploy the app to the server, I get the following error message:

"Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification."

The error is most likely generated from using the GitHub-package "mapDK", but I am clueless how to fix it. Other solutions on the forum regarding launching a shiny app with GitHub packages don't seem to fix the problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(mapDK)


navn<-c("koebenhavn","frederiksberg","ballerup","broendby","dragoer")

navn<-c(navn,navn)

year<-c(rep(2003,5),rep(2004,5))

indicator1<-1:10

indicator2<-10:1

data<-data.frame(cbind(navn,year,indicator1,indicator2))

ui<-fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId="x",label="Indicator",c("Indicator 1"="indicator1","Indicator 2"="indicator2")),

  sliderInput(inputId="y",label="Year",min=2003, max=2004,value=2003,step=1),

  plotOutput("plot")


)


server<-function(session,input,output){

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
  mapDK(values=input$x,id="navn",data=data[data$year==input$y,], map.title=paste(input$x,"in",input$y), guide.label="")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: When I tried to run your app locally I got en error that `mapproj` wasn't installed.  Installing and then adding `library(mapproj)` to the app allowed me to run it.

I suspect you have `mapproj` loaded locally but since it's not in the app itself the app breaks when uploaded.

Comment: Hi Greg, that was it! Now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a side not about the map: you don't have to depend on some unmaintained package for a map of Denmark. You an get a map of Denmark in an R friendly format from Open Street Map:  https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/